# Different solution for a probability question

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-expectation

I got the following problem:

> Find the probability that for two arbitrary numbers $x$ and $y$ with $x,y \in [0,1]$ they satisfy $x+y<1$ and $xy<\frac1{10}$.

In short words the sum of the two numbers is less than $1$ and their product is less than $\frac{1}{10}$.

I am aware that it's possible to solve this using double integrals, that means first to find the total probability which is of course $1$ since $x,y \in [0,1]$ can happen in a square who's edge is $1$.

And for the favourable probability to find the surface on this $1$ by $1$ square who satisfies $x+y <1$ and $xy<\frac{1}{10}$, but I don't have so much knowledge with double integrals, basically to set the bounds for the integrals and so on.

Is there a simpler solution that doesn't require so much analysis knowledge?

Comment: Are you familiar with single integrals and setting their bounds?  if so, you can find the answer with single integrals since the joint PDF is uniform and this problem amounts to finding ratios of areas that can be solved with single integrals.

Comment: @StatsStudent I am familiar mostly with any kind of integrals (single, double, line-integrals, surface integrals), that is how I know that this can be solved using double integrals. My problem is setting their bounds which I'm having hard time with, that is why I'm asking help for an alternative route.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  That's helpful.  Would it be helpful to show you how to find the bounds in double-integrals, or would you prefer we demonstrate how to solve this with a single integral?  It's not clear if you have trouble determining the bounds with single integrals.

Comment: Well, I just want to understand. If it's not possible to avoid analysis then I have plenty of time for any method since I'm in vacation so I will try to read and take any suggestions, but to be honest I don't imagine how single integrals can work here directly. Maybe there is a (pseudo) reduction from double integrals to single ones and it gives the impression that there was a single integral?

Comment: I'll try to put together and example to help you understand.  It will take a bit of time today until I can do it.  Please add the self-study tag though.

Comment: If you want $P(xy<1/10 \cap x+y<1)$, then I see no quick solution.  But it should be pretty straightforward to solve the double integral $\int_0^1 \int_0^{\min(1-x,1/(10x),1)} dy dx$ by breaking it up into three double integrals.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240325/distribution-of-quadratic-equation-roots-where-coefficients-are-generated-unifor/242075#242075 is very closely related.  The techniques used there apply here directly.

Comment: @StatsStudent. Where in the problem is it stated that the joint density has value $1$ on the unit square or equivalently that the random variables are independent and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, the independence was assumed from the question context.  I assumed, and I think correctly, that "for two arbitrary numbers" implied that $x$ was sampled uniformly and independently of $y$.  One would think that if the numbers were selected in some other fashion it would be indicated in the problem statement.  But your point is well taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always a good idea to graph problems like this first. To understand
what to graph exactly, we proceed as follows: First, we can prepare
the graph by initially "framing-out" the area support (or area
where there is positive probability under the joint probability density
function or PDF). In this case both $X$ and $Y$ are independent
and uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$, which implies
that the joint PDF is uniform with PDF given by:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{X,Y}(x,y) & = & \begin{cases}
1, & 0<x<1;\,0<y<1\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray*}

since the joint PDF of two independent random variables is simply
the product of the PDFs of each of the random variables. Now, we know
that the area of positive probability is the area bounded by the unit
square so this can be drawn on our graph (the light purple lines shown
in the graph shown below).

[image]

Now you are being asked to find the probability
that $X$ and $Y$ satisfy $X+Y<1$ and $XY<\frac{1}{10}$. After
re-arranging terms, in symbols, this becomes

\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left(X+Y<1\,\text{and}\,XY<\frac{1}{10}\right) & = & P\left(Y<1-X\,\cap\,Y<\frac{1}{10X}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Geometrically, this amounts to finding the density under the area
bounded by the inequalities $y<1-x$ and $y<\frac{1}{10x}$. We can
draw on our graph the line of $y=1-x$ and shade in pink the area
where $y$ is less than this line. This is shown as the areas marked
as **III** and **IV** on the figure below. Similarly, we can draw the equation
$y=\frac{1}{10x}$ in the area of support and shade in light blue
the area under this equation (areas **I**, **III**, and **V**). Now, note that
we are only interested in the areas that are under **both** $y<1-X$
and $y<\frac{1}{10x}$, within the unit square which is the area where
the pink and blue shading overlaps in the figure, or the area by **III**
and inside the unit square. The probability associated with this area
can be determined in two ways:

1. We can perform single-variable integration in three pieces (or through
   some other single-variable integral with subtraction) and sum the
   resulting areas; or
2. We can perform double-integration of area IV and then subtract this
   from the area of the triangle formed by $y<1-x$ and the unit square
   (areas **III** and **IV**).

I'll show the calculation of both Methods $1$ and $2$.

## Method 1

Because the joint PDF is uniform over the unit square, then the probability
we are seeking is simply the sum of the area of interest since the
density over the entire area of support is constant. Note this method
only works in cases where the joint density is uniform over the area
of positive probability. To use this method, we have to find a suitably
smooth function over which we can integrate. Unfortunately, this doesn't
exist here. However, we can partition the area we are interested in
integrating at point of discontinuity or where the function under
which we want to integrate changes so that the function is piecemeal
smooth. This means we can break the graph into three places by
dropping a vertical line at those points where the graph of $y=1-x$
and $y=\frac{1}{10x}$ intersect (the red and blue dots on **Figure
1**). The second graph, **Figure 2**, shows these points with the corresponding
vertical lines dropped to the $x$-axis that divide up **III** into the
three areas marked by **A**, **B**, and **C**.

[image]

So Areas A and C can be obtained
by integrating under $y=1-x$ from $x=0$ to the first intersecting
points and then from the second intersecting point to $x=1$, respectively.
Area B can be obtained by integrating under the equation $y=\frac{1}{10x}$
between the two points where it intersects with the line given by
$y=1=x$ (the red and blue points).

Before we can proceed with integration we must obtain the bounds of
integration for A, B, and C, so we need to find the $x$-values where
the equations $y=1-x$ and $y=\frac{1}{10x}$ intersect. This can
be found by setting the right-hand-side (RHS) of each equation equal
to one another and then solving for $x$ through the use of the quadratic
formula:

\begin{eqnarray*}
1-x & = & \frac{1}{10x}\\
 & \implies & x(1-x)=\frac{1}{10}\\
 & \implies & x^{2}-x+\frac{1}{10}=0\\
 & \implies & x=\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{5}}\,\text{or}\,x=\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{5}}
\end{eqnarray*}

By substitution, we find that the red point in the graphic is given
by $\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2},\,\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2}\right)$
and the blue point by $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2},\,\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2}\right)$.
Now, we can finally integrate areas A, B, and C with the boundaries
of integration appropriately set:

#### Area A:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2}}1-xdx & = & \left.x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right|_{0}^{\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2}}\\
 & = & \frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{5}}-\frac{5-2\sqrt{5}\sqrt{3}+3}{40}\\
 & \approx & 0.1063508327
\end{eqnarray*}

#### Area B:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{10}\int_{\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2}}^{\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2}}x^{-1}dx & = & \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\left.x^{-1}\right|_{\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2}}^{\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2}}\\
 & = & \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\log\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2}\right)\\
 & = & \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\log\left[\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2}{1-\sqrt{3/5}}\right)\right]\\
 & = & \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}\right)\\
 & \approx & 0.2063437069
\end{eqnarray*}

### Area C:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2}}^{1}1-xdx & = & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{5}}+\frac{5+2\sqrt{5}\sqrt{3}+3}{40}\\
 & = & \frac{5+2\sqrt{5}\sqrt{3}+3}{40}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{5}}\\
 & \approx & 0.0063508327
\end{eqnarray*}

So the total area in **III**, the probability of interest, and the solution
to the problem is given by $\displaystyle{A+B+C=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\right)+\frac{1}{10}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}\right)\approx0.3190453723}$

### Method 2

When you can use double integrals, things become much easier. To use
a double integral, you essentially need to find bounds in the $x$-direction
and $y$-direction for the region you are interested in integrating
the probability density function over (region **III**). In the $x$-direction,
the bounds go from 0 to 1. The lower bound in the $y$-direction is
the $x$- axis. However, again, we see the upper bound in the $y$-direction
is not smooth because of the sudden changes in the bounds of integration
at the break points previously described. But, if you look closely,
you will notice that area IV has a smooth function on both the upper-
and lower-bounds in the $y$-direction and there are single points
in the $x$-direction. So we can find the area of **III** by finding the
area of the pink triangle (area **III** and **IV**) by using the simple geometry
formula $\frac{1}{2}\times \text{base}\times \text{height}$ (you could also use
integration here, but why do more work?) and subtract out the area
of IV found through double-integration. The resulting value will be
the probability we area after. So let's start this method by finding
the area in IV. We know already that this area is bounded on the top
by $y=1-x$ and on the bottom by $y=\frac{1}{10x}$. For the bounds
of $x$ we simply examine the graph and see area IV goes no further
to the left than the red point given by $\left(x=\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2},\,y=\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2}\right)$
and no further to the right than the blue point given by $\left(x=\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2},\,y=\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2}\right)$.
The $x$-values at these points will serve as the upper and lower
bounds in the direction of $x$. So now, we proceed to computing the
integral, the area of IV, or the probability of interest under the
density function $f_{X},_{Y}(x,y)=1$ bounded by the region given
by IV:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{Area IV} & = & \int_{\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2}}^{\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2}}\int_{\frac{x^{-1}}{10}}^{1-x}1dydx\\
 & = & \int_{\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2}}^{\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2}}1-x-\frac{x^{-1}}{10}dx\\
 & = & \left.x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{10}\log(x)\right|_{\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2}}^{\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2}}\\
 & = & \left[\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2}-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2}\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{10}\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3/5}}{2}\right)\right]-\left[\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2}-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2}\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{10}\log\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3/5}}{2}\right)\right]\\
 & = & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{5}}{10}+\frac{1}{10}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}\right)\\
 & = & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{5}}+\frac{1}{10}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

And finally, to calculate the probability of interest, we simply need
to subtract the probability calculated immediately above (**Area IV**)
from the area of the triangle with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,1)$
(**Area III** and **IV**):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{Area III} & = & \text{Area III}+\text{Area IV}-\text{Area IV}\\
 & = & \text{Triangle with vertices at}\,(0,0)\,(0,1)\,(1,0)-\text{Area IV}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{2}\left(\text{base}\right)\left(\text{height}\right)-\text{Area IV}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{2}(1)(1)-\left[\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{5}}+\frac{1}{10}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]\\
 & = & \frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{5}}-\frac{1}{10}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}\right)\\
 & \approx & 0.3190453723
\end{eqnarray*}

and this is the same answer as the one we obtained using Method 1.$\blacksquare$

Comment: No problem.  I tried to be a detailed as possible to help you grasp both the single integral approach as well as the double-integral approach and how to find the boundaries.

Comment: +1 for drawing the picture.  But seeing it ought to suggest exploiting its symmetry: change the variables $(X,Y)$ to $U=(X-Y)/\lambda$ and $V=(X+Y)/\lambda$ with $\lambda^2=10/4.$  The problem quickly simplifies to computing an integral of the form $$\int_0^\sqrt{\lambda^2-1}\left(\lambda- \sqrt{1+x^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x.$$ (This is proportional to half the area of the pink lune in your picture.)  At that point, consult any Calculus textbook or table of integrals.

Comment: It's an excellent point, @whuber, but I was afraid to further complicate an explanation for the OP who has already expressed trepidation when computing boundaries.  I didn't want to introduce additional topics at once, but I'm glad you did for other who might come along and find the post.

Comment: Awesome to hear, @Reformed!  Glad this could help.  Do try to enhance your learning too with the code provided by @user2974951.  It's a good technique that can usually be used to verify answers (and sometimes get the answers when analytical techniques fail).  R is freely downloadable.

Comment: I understand and appreciate your motivation.  I was concerned only that the basic *statistical* idea might have been lost in all the calculations that followed, which although perhaps of some practical importance to the student, are conceptually irrelevant.

Comment: It's a fair point, @whuber. I erred on the side of detail, perhaps incorrectly, as I assumed the OP is a new learner who might need some additional detail.  I think it paid off though, since, the OP has reported understanding the explanation "perfectly." Whether the concepts are fully understood and the material retained is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively using simulations

```
> x=runif(1e6)
> y=runif(1e6)
> mean(ifelse(x+y<1 & x*y<0.1,T,F))

[1] 0.319823
```

**Edit:** explanation of what is going on

we simulate 1 million random numbers (1e6) from the (standard) uniform distribution (so range 0 to 1), for both $x$ and $y$ coordinates (paired points $x$ and $y$). Then we simply check how many of these coordinates satisfy your conditions, and we take the average. This is your result.

Comment: Thanks! What program is this? And where can I learn to do it for myself?

Comment: @Reformed R (https://www.r-project.org/).

Comment: @Reformed There is plenty of material online for R, a quick google search will give you all the information you need. Also it is quite commonly used on this site.

Comment: This is an excellent method, but removes the OP from understanding the probabilistic and geometrical concepts of the problem.  When first learning, I always advocate using simulation to enhance learning and verifying results, but I advocate against its sole use when first learning and when exact answers are needed.  Also, it's helpful when posting code to explain what the code is doing.  Indeed, the OP isn't even familiar with R, so I'd recommend updating with explanation.

Comment: @StatsStudent I agree, this is just a dirty numerical result. It was meant as an addition to your answer.

Comment: Where exactly in this code makes the range 0 to 1? Also what is the meaning of that "ifelse" there?

Comment: @Reformed The `runif` function (which samples randomly from the uniform distribution) by default uses the standard normal distribution, so the code is equivalent to `runif(1e6,0,1)`. `ifelse` check whether the first argument is true, if it is it returns the second argument, else the third argument.